# Where should I put ssl cert (backend or frontend)?

Tags: tls, web-application

I have two applications: One is Backend API and the second is frontend. I want to add SSL certificate.

Both applications are visible via the Internet, one on port x (backend) and another on y (frontend). A client connects to frontend and then frontend connects to backend in order to get data.

Where should I put the certificate on the frontend or backend part?

Comment: What are the domain names? I.e are they subdomained? I would put it on both if they are living on the same parent domain. Defiantly on the one the client is connecting to (the frontend).

Answer (score 4):

Ideally, the connections from the Internet to your front-end and the connections from your front-end to back-end both need to be protected using SSL. Whatever is serving your front-end / back-end applications would most likely support SSL termination. Your front-end is most likely served by a web server like Nginx or Apache. You need to get the web server to listen over port 443 and [setup SSL](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html) there.

If your back-end application is secure and isolated behind a firewall, and if (and only if) it's configured to receive traffic only from your front-end application, you can optionally skip setting up SSL between the applications. This is NOT recommended, however. Certificates are [cheap if not free](https://letsencrypt.org/) these days and you should aim to set it up wherever possible. There are even [performance benefits](https://www.troyhunt.com/i-wanna-go-fast-https-massive-speed-advantage/) to this and this lets you use fast, modern transport protocols like [HTTP/2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP/2) or SPDY.

Depending on your setup, you could even terminate the SSL at the load balancers if you use them. May I ask why your back-end app is open to Internet?

Comment: Currently, my backend app is not open to the Internet. I still must configure it. There is no need to put my back-end app open to the Internet.

Comment: Right. I asked because you said "Both applications are visible via the Internet" and I mistook it to have meant that the back-end is openly accessible from the Internet. Hope my answer helped.